# Marketing Cloud Engagement - Can Data View retention periods be shortened?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms, data-views

My understanding is that the default retention period for data views is 6 months.

Is there an option to reduce or extend this retention period? I am looking to minimise the amount of SMS message tracking info that gets logged within [SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5), [SMSSubscriptionLog](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_subscription_log.htm&type=5), [Undeliverable SMS](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_undeliverable_sms.htm&type=5) as well as any other applicable SMS views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot extend the Data views retention period but you can limit the results you find based on a date field by SQL query.

Here is an example SQL query where I pull the results in a day before.

```SQL
SELECT
      smsTracking.Sent
    , smsTracking.Delivered
    , smsTracking.Undelivered
    , smsTracking.CreateDateTime
    , smsTracking.ModifiedDateTime
    , smsTracking.ActionDateTime
    , smsTracking.MessageText
FROM _SMSMessageTracking AS smsTracking
WHERE smsTracking.CreateDateTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```